# CSRF verification failed on authorization

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

When I'm trying to authorize by

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=myusername&password=mypassword" http://localhost:8000/oauth2/authorize/
```

I get 403 forbidden: CSRF validation failed. Request aborted. I can't understand why, any help would be appreciated.

By the way I use Django OAuth Toolkit for authentication.

Edit: I know about CSRF protection and how to use it in django view and forms, I'm using a package called Django OAuth Toolkit for oauth 2 authorization which  shouldn't ask for csrf token. There is a little information [here](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-1-minimal-setup) about what I'm tring to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm ashamed to say that I was sending the request to wrong url, I should have sent it to `http://localhost:8000/oauth2/token/`

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=myusername&password=mypassword&client_id=myclientid"  http://localhost:8000/oauth2/token/
```

Comment: Same exact thing just happened to me. Thanks for documenting the solution.

Comment: Thanks!  Mine was even more subtle than that.  The trailing slash on the url is vital when using curl to refresh a token - you get the csrf validation error without it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add csrf token in your POST data.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: I know about CSRF protection and how to use it in django view and forms, I'm using a package called Django OAuth Toolkit for oauth 2 authorization which shouldn't ask for csrf token.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth your while reading the documentation on Django's built in [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/).

Any post to a Django view will need the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` set, otherwise you'll get a 403. You'll need to either include it, or [exempt your view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) from CSRF protection (prefer the former approach if possible).

Comment: I know about CSRF protection and how to use it in django view and forms, I'm using a package called Django OAuth Toolkit for oauth 2 authorization which  shouldn't ask for csrf token.